# Visual Studio 2017 - IntelliSense does not recognise identifiers

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, intellisense

I'm having a problem with a Visual Studio project and IntelliSense. Since upgrading to VS 2017 (it worked fine in 2010), IntelliSense has been complaining that standard library functions do not exist (For example: `time`, `memcpy`, `rand`) with the error `identifier "time" is undefined`.

Additionally, some (but not all) standard header files give the error that they cannot be opened. For example, the source file I'm viewing right now claims `cannot open source file "direct.h"`, while header files like `winsock2.h` are not a problem.

I suspect the problem lies completely within IntelliSense, since the project compiles fine and all 'unindentified' functions run and perform as expected. However, I have no idea which setting to change or how to reset IntelliSense in order to once again recognise the different identifiers.

Comment: If you create a new C++ console application to test those complaining content, this issue persists or not? If not, please right click this solution name and ‘Clean solution’, close VS and delete the hidden folder ‘.vs’, reopen vs to open this solution again. If this issue occurs for all project, please run the command: devenv /safemode to run VS with safe mode that can help us to check if the installed extension made this or re-run the VS installer as administrator and choose to repair it.

Comment: same for me on opencv